# Why would PHP-generated Javascript not work in file loaded via AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, extjs

I am loading a `.php` file via an ExtJS AJAX call like this:

```
menuItemApplication.header.on('click', function() {             
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'content/view_application.php',
        success: function(objServerResponse) {
            var responseText = objServerResponse.responseText;
            regionContent.update(responseText);
            var scripts, scriptsFinder=/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]+)<\/script>/gi;
            while(scripts=scriptsFinder.exec(responseText)) {
                eval(scripts[1]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Javascript in the loaded .php file executes fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     regionContent.update('changed region content from within application view');
</script>
```

But if the **Javascript** is being generated via **PHP**, it is **not executed**:

```
<?php
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
echo "regionContent.update('changed region content from within application view')';\n";
echo "</script>\n";
?>
```

Yes the responses are the same, as seen in the Firebug Net panel, here with Javascript which  **works**:

[image]

And here with PHP-generated Javascript, which **does not work**:

[image]

**How can I get the PHP-generated Javascript to execute?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those responses aren't the same. Check the '; versus ; at the end there.

```
<?php
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
echo "regionContent.update('changed region content from within application view')';\n";
echo "</script>\n";
?>
```

Versus

```
<?php
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
echo "regionContent.update('changed region content from within application view');\n";
echo "</script>\n";
?>
```

Comment: Its such an easy mistake to make. I'm surprised the error console didn't let you know what's up.

Answer (score 2):

There's an extra quote in your PHP code, causing the quotes in Javascript to work incorrectly; instead of:

```
echo "regionContent.update('changed region content from within application view')';\n";
```

You need:

```
echo "regionContent.update('changed region content from within application view');\n";
```