# Rejoining a chrome.cast.Session in an ajax app?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

Our site uses ajax to navigate pages and that's making it hard to request a new session when the page changes.  Ideally when a user changes pages, I'd like to stop the currently playing session and start a new session with the video that's on the new page.

On the first pageload, I append the https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js script, call the init method:

```
var sessionRequest = new chrome.cast.SessionRequest(applicationID);
var apiConfig = new chrome.cast.ApiConfig(sessionRequest,
this.sessionListener.bind(this),
this.receiverListener.bind(this));
chrome.cast.initialize(apiConfig, this.onInitSuccess.bind(this), this.onError.bind(this));
```

everything works fine, my callbacks are called and I can start the chromecast session.

On secondary page loads, I don't re-add the cast_sender.js script. When I call the initalize method and the sessionListener callback doesn't execute. If I try holding on to the session between pages, I can access the session and get to it's media object, but if I try calling any methods on the session or media object, I just get back an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'postMessage' of null
```

Seems like there's some magic binding that happens when executing the cast_sender.js script that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you played with the AutoJoinPolicy?      https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.AutoJoinPolicy

Comment: Yeah, tried playing with both the AutoJoinPolicy and DefaultActionPolicy and neither seem to have any effect.

Comment: Your secondary page is loaded via ajax call?  If so, try to load the cast_sender.js asynchronously.  See how to do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097026/how-to-run-javascript-in-html-loaded-via-ajax

Comment: Yeah, when I load async things work, but the listeners start piling up. So on the second pageview I get two notifications from various callbacks (callbacks I created and mystery ones in the chromecast library), on third pageview, I get three notifications etc.

Answer (score 0):

We've just released the Google Cast extension Beta that potentially addresses this issue.  See my post: https://plus.google.com/+ShawnShen/posts/aVXSHyceNbR

You may add something like the following in your app to do both sync/async script loading.

window['_*onGCastApiAvailable'] = (function(loaded, errorInfo) {
    if (loaded) {
      this.init*();
    } else {
      this.appendMessage_(errorInfo);
    }
  }).bind(this);